# Does not have a main method error after adding event handling code

Tags: java, swing, awt

i just started learning JAVA and im having this error in netbeans saying that the class that im trying to run does not have a main method and it happens everytime i try add some event handling codes (ex. mouseCLicked). When i remove those newly added codes, the programs then starts to run without any issues. Here's the code, most of it is generated by netbeans.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.*;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author LESTER
 */
public class Dashboard_Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form Dashboard_Form */
    
    Border default_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, new Color(46, 49, 49));
        
    Border yellow_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.yellow);
        
    public Dashboard_Form() {
        initComponents();
        
        jLabel_appLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("IMAGES/appLogo.png")));
        Border panelBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.white);
        jPanel_logoAndName.setBorder(panelBorder);
       
    }
    
    /*public void AddActiontoMenuLabels()
    {
        Component[] components = jPanel_menu.getComponents();
         
        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) component;
                
                label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Hey.");
            }
        });
            }
        }
    }
    */
    

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel_menu = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel_logoAndName = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel_appLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel_dashboard = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel27 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel18 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel20 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel19 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel23 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel24 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel21 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel22 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel8 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel25 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel26 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel_menu.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(46, 49, 46));

        jPanel_logoAndName.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(46, 49, 46));

        jLabel_appLogo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 204));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));
        jLabel8.setText("MyApp");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel_logoAndNameLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel_logoAndName);
        jPanel_logoAndName.setLayout(jPanel_logoAndNameLayout);
        jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(22, 22, 22)
                .add(jLabel_appLogo, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(jLabel8, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 104, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(18, 18, 18))
        );
        jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(25, 25, 25)
                .add(jPanel_logoAndNameLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(jLabel8, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jLabel_appLogo, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("       Users");
        jLabel2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("       Products");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("       Settings");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("       Contacts");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("       Calendar");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("       Test");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel_menuLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel_menu);
        jPanel_menu.setLayout(jPanel_menuLayout);
        jPanel_menuLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel_menuLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel_logoAndName, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jLabel7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel_menuLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel_menuLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel_menuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jPanel_logoAndName, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(61, 61, 61)
                .add(jLabel2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jLabel3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jLabel4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jLabel5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jLabel6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(jLabel7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(0, 125, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel_dashboard.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));

        jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel15.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel15.setText("128");

        jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel16.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel16.setText("Products are currently in the store");

        jLabel27.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 204));
        jLabel27.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel27.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel27.setText("   Sales");
        jLabel27.setOpaque(true);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(100, 100, 100)
                .add(jLabel15, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .add(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel16, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jLabel27, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jLabel27, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel15)
                .add(34, 34, 34)
                .add(jLabel16)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 255));

        jLabel11.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 204));
        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel11.setText("   Revenue");
        jLabel11.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel18.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel18.setText("Revenue in the past 30 days");

        jLabel20.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel20.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel20.setText("$ 28933.78");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jLabel11, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel18, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(63, 63, 63)
                .add(jLabel20)
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jLabel11, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(31, 31, 31)
                .add(jLabel20)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel18)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 0));

        jLabel10.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 0));
        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel10.setText("   Sales");
        jLabel10.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel17.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel17.setText("Sales in the past 30 days");

        jLabel19.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel19.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel19.setText("94220");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jLabel10, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel17, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(93, 93, 93)
                .add(jLabel19, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jLabel10, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel19)
                .add(30, 30, 30)
                .add(jLabel17)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));

        jLabel13.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));
        jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel13.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel13.setText("   Refunds");
        jLabel13.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel23.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel23.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel23.setText("$ 28933.45");

        jLabel24.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel24.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel24.setText("*Last 30 days");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
        jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
        jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jLabel13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(67, 67, 67)
                    .add(jLabel23, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jLabel13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel24)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(62, 62, 62)
                    .add(jLabel23)
                    .addContainerGap(62, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        jPanel7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

        jLabel12.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 0));
        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel12.setText("   Net Profit");
        jLabel12.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel21.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel21.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel21.setText("$ 28933.98");

        jLabel22.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel22.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel22.setText("*Last 30 days");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout jPanel7Layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(jPanel7);
        jPanel7.setLayout(jPanel7Layout);
        jPanel7Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jLabel12, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .add(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(61, 61, 61)
                .add(jLabel21)
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel7Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(jLabel12, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(27, 27, 27)
                .add(jLabel21)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel22)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));

        jLabel14.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 204));
        jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel14.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel14.setText("   Compare to Last 30 Days");
        jLabel14.setOpaque(true);

        jLabel25.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel25.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel25.setText("*In Sales");

        jLabel26.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel26.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel26.setText("+ 2.56%");

        
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // this is the event code, just to try if it will work
        System.out.println("Clicked.");
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Dashboard_Form().setVisible(true);
            
        }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel18;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel19;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel20;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel21;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel22;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel23;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel24;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel25;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel26;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel27;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_appLogo;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_dashboard;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_logoAndName;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_menu;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Im trying to follow a tutorial from youtube in creating a simple login interface with two windows but i havent incorporated the windows with each other. Im still in the process of testing simple events like mouse click but cant move further because of the error. i also removed some of the layout part to avoid exceeding the character limit.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Event handling code is not a main method.  NetBeans either means you picked the wrong project type (you picked a "library" when you should have picked a "desktop app" or similar).  Or you did pick a correct project type but deleted the main method.  You can check your project type and main method in the project Properties.  Please take a look at that and tell us what you have there.

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial.  The main method is the one that is written `public static void main(String[] args)` and it does have to match exactly.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: Where's the event handling code you tried to add?  You're more likely to get help if you show us the code that _doesn't_ work, not the code that _does_.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It should be possible to do that with *far* less than 500 lines of code. Speaking of which, try to reproduce the problem with just two labels rather than the 27 listed.  2) Give attributes meaningful, descriptive names! 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) & use it consistently. Don't include the `_` char unless a constant.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I *think* the event handler is buried in their code, it's the part that is commented out.  OP: I can't reproduce your problem.  The event handler above doesn't appear to have any errors, so it's not causing your main method to mess up.  Please **trim your code** down to something both you and us can agree reproduces the problem.

Comment: I wondered that, @markspace, but it didn't completely match up with what OP was talking about, so I thought it would be better to ask, rather than assume.  Right now, we're all chasing shadows - I don't think any of us really know _what_ it is that doesn't work for OP.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem *"we're all chasing shadows"* Careful with use of 'all'. I voted to close. If the OP posts an MRE / SSCCE, I'll remove the close vote and look into it. But I'm not spending time speculating before then.

Comment: True that.  I suspect this may be a case of "I'll ask a question and go to bed, and someone will have answered by the time I wake up".  Which is an almost guaranteed path to not getting an answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem *"Which is an almost guaranteed path to not getting an answer. "* Imagine their shock when they check it next morning, to find it closed. ;)

Comment: Hi @markspace, i followed your suggestion and checked the properties. i changed the selected main class and pointed it to the window the code above is in. im now able to run my code without any issues. it seems that this is just a matter of me still unfamiliar to the IDE that im using. Thank you very much for the quick response, and to everyone else who took notice and spent a minute to reply, i really appreciate it.

Comment: OK, so occasionally NB forgets your main class and you have to set it again.  It's good you learned something.  Read through those properties on occasion and experiment with them, they're handy to know what's available.